# load images from assets at runtime without lifting sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Is there anyway to load images from assets at runtime without lifting sails? I uploaded a image but wen i tried to view it, it gives an error in console
`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:1337/Questions/formula/DC626DA5-068B-3C84-44F0-D7A9F1828F67.JPG"`

Comment: why would you need to access the images without lifting sails..?

Comment: Cause i need to see the image at runtime as a result.

Comment: I managed to view the image in windows by creating a symlink to assets image but it doesnt work in linux.